# Order list with vue-slicksort

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using [vue-slicksort](https://github.com/Jexordexan/vue-slicksort) on Vue.js, and I am trying to change `order_no` with the index value after sorting is complete. But I don't even access the method. And the second thing is that I am trying to list all elements after `order_no` (ex. 1,4 5, 7) = `order_nr` value.

```js
<SortableList lockAxis="y" v-model="table">
        <SortableItem 
            v-for="(item, index) in table"
            :index="index"
            :key="index"
            :item="item"
            @sort-end="changeOrderElement(index)"/>
</SortableList>

changeOrderElement(index){
    console.log('Order:', this.table.order_no);
    this.table.order_no = index;
    console.log('New Order:', this.table.order_no);
}
```

Comment: Do you put your method ```changeOrderElement``` in a method block?

Comment: Yes, is in a method.

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution?